# mfc dll loads and unloads itself immediately

Tags: dynamic, dll, mfc, loading

This time i am messing around with dynamic dll loading. after dealing with numerous linker errors i finally got things to compile but my dll file is not loading itself. I did everything more or less in the way it is discussed here: http://www.programmingforums.org/thread21690.html
In general, i want to create an object of a class defined in the dll i have prepared and loaded.

Function which loades the dll looks like this:

```
void CData::OnButton2()
{

HINSTANCE hDLL=NULL;               // Handle to DLL

typedef void (*GETDLLOBJECT)(IProcess**);
TRACE(_T("button2\n"));
hDLL = AfxLoadLibrary(_T("ImagePerspectiveComputation.dll"));
if (hDLL != NULL)
{
    TRACE(_T("library loaded\n"));
  GETDLLOBJECT StworzObjekt = (GETDLLOBJECT)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"CreateTheObject");
   if (!StworzObjekt)
   {
//       handle the error
//same irrelevant code here
   }
   else
   {
//same irrelevant code here too
   }

}else
    TRACE(_T("failed loading\n"));
}
```

the .h file of the file in which i'm declaring a class being exported:

```
#include <atlimage.h>
#include <afx.h>

#ifdef DLLMESSAGE
#define PORT __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define PORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

using namespace std;


class PORT IProcess
{
public:
    IProcess(void);
    IProcess(CString fotka);
    virtual ~IProcess(void);
    virtual void SetImagePath(CString fotka);
    virtual CImage GetCorners(int* pointx,int* pointy,int* pointnumber,int blocksize,double ksize,int aperturesize);
    virtual void GetTransformMatrix(int pointnum, CPoint *input,CPoint *desired,double** result);
private:
    CString obraz;
};
extern "C" PORT void CreateTheObject(IProcess **objekt);

extern "C" PORT IProcess* CreateTheObjectParam(CString fotka);
```

There are no errors or warnings, however i'm getting this in the output section:

bylo!

button2

'PhotoInterface.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\BART\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PhotoInterface1\PhotoInterface\ImagePerspectiveComputation.dll', Symbols loaded.

'PhotoInterface.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Users\BART\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PhotoInterface1\PhotoInterface\ImagePerspectiveComputation.dll'

failed loading

wszedl

which suggests that the dll is loaded and unloaded giving me the hDLL equal NULL.
Is there something wrong with my linking? or maybe is it because i did nothing with the main class of the dll? (the one which is derived from CWinApp). I haven't seen any article about necessity of doing something with it, apart from some optional initialization code (which i ignored).

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

edit: 
Edward Clements had very good suggestion. at first i got error 126, which at first was very weird to me, as misspelled dll name wouldn't give me the load-unload message. I did run the dependency walker and found a number of problems: lack of opencv dlls at runtime (temporary fixed by placing them in the same folder) and what was more challenging the lack of msvcp110d.dll and msvcr110d.dll

Comment: Try calling `GetLastError()` when the DLL handle is null, see [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582(v=vs.85).aspx) on how to display the corresponding message text.

Comment: Since it's telling you that the dll was wrongly named I suggest you pursue this line of enquiry rather than assuming that the OS is wrong ;)